# vb.net IO.StreamWriter only works in debug mode

Tags: vb.net

It works perfectly in debug mode but it gives me 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' unhandled exception error when I run the built one and press the Save button(It loads but not saves after that).
Any advice, please.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class DL1

    Function DirExists(ByVal DirName As String) As Boolean
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        DirExists = GetAttr(DirName) And vbDirectory
ErrorHandler:
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadGlink_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadGlink.Click

        GlinkList.Items.Clear()



        Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        fileReader = _
        My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("c:\Source\DL1\Glink.txt")

        Dim mystring() As String = fileReader.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine)


        GlinkList.Items.AddRange(mystring)

        fileReader.Close()

        Me.Controls("Glinklist").Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub linktochrome_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles linktochrome.Click
        If GlinkList.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            ' selected item is sglink
            Dim sglink = GlinkList.SelectedItem.ToString


            Process.Start("C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", sglink)
        End If
        Me.Controls("Glinklist").Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub movetofol_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles movetofol.Click



        Dim strDir As String
        strDir = "C:\Users\1\Downloads\Glink\" & "\" & SFoltext.Text
        If DirExists(Trim(strDir)) = False Then
            MkDir(Trim(strDir))
        End If


        For Each f As String In Sresult1.Items
            Dim f_name As String = Path.GetFileName(f)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(f, strDir & "\" & f_name)
        Next
        Sresult1.Items.Clear()

        GlinkList.Items.Remove(GlinkList.SelectedItem)


    End Sub

    Private Sub ChecKDL_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChecKDL.Click

        Sresult1.Items.Clear()
        Dim fileList As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
        fileList = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Users\1\Downloads\")


        For Each foundFile As String In fileList
            Sresult1.Items.Add(foundFile)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Bsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Bsave.Click
        Dim i As Integer


        'Saves Glinklist
        Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine("c:\Source\DL1\", "Glink.txt")
        Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(path, IO.FileMode.Create)

            Using w As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(fs)
                For i = 0 To GlinkList.Items.Count - 1
                    w.WriteLine(GlinkList.Items.Item(i))
                Next
                w.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub RMselec_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RMselec.Click
        GlinkList.Items.Remove(GlinkList.SelectedItem)
        Me.Controls("Glinklist").Focus()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Not an answer, but are you aware of [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx)? Might be preferred to manually opening/splitting the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it this could be the answer, but I will post here because I can better format the code.
Let me know if this changes anything

Change your reading function to

```
Using fileReader = _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("c:\Source\DL1\Glink.txt")
    Dim mystring() = fileReader.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine)
    GlinkList.Items.AddRange(mystring)
End Using
```

Or simply

```
    Dim mystring() = File.ReadAllLines()
    GlinkList.Items.AddRange(mystring)
```

Comment: Using fileReader = _
     My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("c:\Source\DL1\Glink.txt")
            Dim mystring() = File.ReadAllLine()

            GlinkList.Items.AddRange(mystring)
        End Using 'ReadAllLine is not a member of System.IO.file. It says

Comment: +1 for bringing this to peoples attention, however the OP is manually closing the reader with `fileReader.Close()`.

Comment: File.ReadAllLines() is a static method of the File class. You don't need the StreamReader. The second example is an alternative to the Whole using block

Comment: Fixed typo on ReadAllLines

Comment: readalllines("c:\Source\DL1\glink.txt") method was much simpler. Thank you. However I tried them both but they give the same error.

Comment: File.Copy(Path.Combine("c:\Source\DL1\", "Glinksave.txt"), Path.Combine("c:\Source\DL1\", "Glink.txt"), True)'I tried to save the list ti another text file then overwrite the original when load is clicked. It was done to avoid read and write is done on the same file. I have found out filecopy wouldn't work when I build the program. File copying and writing only works when its run in visual studio debug mode. Is it windows 7 file protection or something?

Comment: It should work as is, have you checked if the folder has read/write permission for the user running your program?

Comment: Wow, its working now. I've changed compile option to strict and it said I need to change DirExists = GetAttr(DirName) vbDirectory part to DirExists = CBool(GetAttr(DirName) And vbDirectory) and then it works fine. I still don't understand why it didn't work but it is working now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Good for you, but that code is not used against the folder locked. However, replace it with Directory.Exists static method.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means a permission issue. Try running Visual Studio as admin to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: It works well when I run it in visual studio. It doesn't work when I build it to DL1.exe and run it. It crashes when I click load text file then save it. I tried your advice. Sadly, it didn't work.